# zsh alias for screen with logging?

Tags: zsh

I have this:

```
alias screener="screen -Logfile ~/$1.log -L -S $1"
```

But the logging part isn't working.

If I run it manually e.g. `screen -Logfile ~/foo.log -L -S foo"` I see the expected behavior: output saved to `foo.log` in my home directory. Alias, no go on the logging.

Comment: Alias don't support parameters, use a function instead. There should be a lot of examples "alias vs. function" on SU.

Comment: Yeah, function works better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Made this is a function, works.

```
screener() {
    screen -Logfile ~/screen.$1.log -L -S $1
}
```

Then `screener foo`